# My state array gets emptied every time i call a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, use-state

I have this:

```
const BillsOverviewScreen = props => {
const { navigation } = props;

const [availableBills, setAvailableBills] = useState([]);

const bills = useSelector(state => state.bills.bills);

useEffect (() => {
    setAvailableBills(bills);
}, [bills]);


const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(billsActions.loadBills());
}, [dispatch]);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (   
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <SortingMenu sortBills={sortBills} />
                <FilterMenu />                   
            </View>                            

        ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

function sortBills(sortBy) {
    
    switch (sortBy) {
        case 'title': {
             setAvailableBills(availableBills.sort((a, b) => a.title < b.title ? -1 : (a.title > b.title ? 1 : 0)))
            break;
        };
        case 'dateExpiry_up': {
             setAvailableBills(availableBills.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.dateExpiry) - new Date(a.dateExpiry)));  
            break;        
        };
        case 'dateExpiry_down': {
            setAvailableBills(availableBills.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.dateExpiry) - new Date(b.dateExpiry)));  
            break;          
        };
        case 'dateCreated_up': {
            setAvailableBills(availableBills.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.dateCreated) - new Date(a.dateCreated)));
            break;
        };
        case 'dateCreated_down': {
            setAvailableBills(availableBills.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.dateCreated) - new Date(b.dateCreated)));
            break;
        };
        default: 
            return availableBills
            
    }
}
```

Initially my state availableBills array gets filled as intended with the right data, but as soon as i use my sortBills function the array is empty. The weird thing is sometimes when i play around with it, its working. But when i reset my app its empty again. I really dont know what im doing wrong. tried different things but cant solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` does an in-place mutation, so you are mutating the state and not really ever updating it.

[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array *in place* and returns
> the sorted array.

Shallow copy the state first, then sort it, using `.slice` easily creates a copy inline. I suggest using a functional state update for this. The functional state update avoids stale state enclosures by updating from the previous state versus the value of `availableBills` closed over in callback scope.

```
setAvailableBills(availableBills => 
  availableBills.slice().sort((a, b) => 
    a.title < b.title ? -1 : (a.title > b.title ? 1 : 0)
));
```

Apply this pattern across all your cases.

Comment: Great! that just solved everything. thank you! i was thinking i did something wrong with the way i was using my useEffects, because at the initial loading i couldnt even see my data getting passed into the function, but i guess its all good.